# How do I check if a sequence of R-modules is exact?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, computer-algebra

Let R be a ring. For example, take $R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ or, if possible, $R = \Bbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.

Consider a sequence of free R-modules
$$R^a \stackrel{f}\to R^b \stackrel{g}\to R^c$$
where $f$ and $g$ are explicitly given by appropriately sized matrices.

How does one check (in practice, presumably(?) on a computer) whether or not this sequence is exact?

Comment: Macaulay2 has "kernel" and "image" commands. Don't they do it? http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.8.1/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/___Matrix.html

Comment: To be more explicit about the mathematics involved, computer-algorithms for calculating images and kernels (and a host of other things) over commutative rings all use [Groebner Bases](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Groebner_basis) techniques.  However, for an easier necessary condition, if $gf=0$, you can tensor with the field of fractions of $R$ and do linear algebra.  This cannot prove exactness, but it will quickly eliminate things that aren't exact.

Comment: If you want to check by hand, you can use Buchsbaum-Eisenbud criterion. You can find it in their paper: *What makes a complex exact?* I think published in 1973.